# TCPDF Template - Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php, tcpdf

And have a template for that one creating the page I want.
I have function TextBox($ ---- and template settings)

When I run this once it create the page, when I have it in a cron it only runs once before trowing an error in php like this

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare TextBox() (previously declared in pdf.tpl:7) in pdf.tpl on line 12

Here is my code from line 7-13

```
function TextBox($pdf,$textval, $x = 0, $y, $width = 0, $height = 10, $fontsize = 8, $fontstyle = '', $align = 'L',$ltr='',$fil='') {
    $pdf->SetXY($x+15, $y); // 20 = margin left
    $pdf->SetFont('freesans', $fontstyle, $fontsize);
    $pdf->Cell($width, $height, $textval,$ltr,false , $align,$fil);

}
$startpage = $pdf->GetPage();
```

Comment: only runs once then error?, sounds like you have the function defined in a loop ??

Comment: Are you running an include and put that include which contains that function in a for loop? if you did, that would be a mistake, and one of the ways you may have gotten the error. Make sure you run include_once instead of include to avoid these types of issues.

Comment: Thanks I had the function in the template it self. I took the function out to a seperate php file and then just included it once int the template.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox is a function name TCPDF also uses. Choose an other one.